# How do I handle var (or ref) parameters in COM Interop?

Tags: c#, delphi, com, com-interop

I have a stand-alone application which exposes COM Interfaces/CoClasses/Enums, etc. One of those interfaces exports the following function:

```
procedure FindTask(const TaskId: WideString; var Task: OleVariant); safecall;
```

Note: `Task` is also exposed as a `CoClass`. 
Note: `Task` is [in, out]

So far, my legacy application, which is also written in Delphi, had been able to communicate with the stand-alone application. Consider that stand-alone app as an out-of-proc COM server and consider this legacy app as a client app.

As I am rewriting the old Delphi app (client) in C#, I have to use COM Interop in C# to communicate with that application. Therefore, I made use of tlbimp.exe to translate those COM interfaces to C# interfaces.

That method was translated as following:

```
void FindTask(string, TaskId, ref object Task);
```

How can I call FindTask and receive the result of an already existent task with this signature?

I've tried this: (Task is the CoClass type)

```
ScTask target = new CsTask();
scheduler.FindTask("A GUID value", ref target);
```

But the compiler yelled about the type, since there is no overload with that class type (the translated method receives an object)

Could I do this, instead?

```
object target = new object();
scheduler.FindTask("A GUID value", ref target);
ScTask translated = (ScTask) target;
```

How can I call a method that expects an `var` `(in, out)` `Variant *`, therefore translated as object, but that actually have a more precise type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rather looks to me as though the parameter is really an out parameter. You don't actually appear to be attempting to pass anything in. The method appears to be returning a different object. So in the C# it ought to be:

```
void FindTask(string TaskId, out object Task);
```

You'd then call it like this:

You'd need to change the type library to specify out semantics.

If it really is in/out then you'd keep the use of `ref` and call the method like this:

```
object target = null;
scheduler.FindTask("A GUID value", ref target);
ScTask translated = (ScTask) target;
```

Or possibly pass in an actual object with meaningful state if that's how it is designed to work.

Comment: You are right, David. It should be [out, retval]. I didn't designed that, it is just stupid to be [in, out]. Well, I can't change, now... too much backward compatibility problems, I will use `target = null` instead of `new object()`;